# How to make Samba4 Internal DNS resolve names without domain

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, samba

I have a Samba4 AD-DC configured with internal DNS. I followed the configuration at https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller
   I use this samba as my DNS for the network, but I find that it does not resolve names that don't have the domain suffix.
Example:

```
# dig tarl.domain.example.com
...

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tarl.domain.example.com.         IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
tarl.domain.example.com.  900     IN      A       10.0.0.2
...
```

But, if I query without domain:

```
# dig tarl
...
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tarl.                          IN      A
...
```

I have read and searched but could not find how to make Samba DNS resolve without domains. All I found was configuring DHCP to send a list of domains to try for these cases, but I prefer samba to handle this.

Thanks in Advance!
Regards.

Comment: This is managed by the search suffix defined in `/etc/resolv.conf`. If this device has a static IP, change the file by hand. If it receives a dynamic IP, adjust settings on the DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows DNS, single-name resolution is handled by adding a GlobalNames zone to DNS.

I realize this isn't an answer, but my "points" didn't allow me to leave a comment. This info may help, feel free to convert it to a comment.